# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while using SAX XMI parser

Tags: java, static, variable-assignment, initializer, xmi

I'm trying to parse some XMI tags in here. And though my code is compiled properly.

I'm getting following runtime error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: findlocationmessage.Lifeline`
```

My code is:

```
public class FindLocationMessage extends DefaultHandler{
    public static List<Lifeline> lifelineList;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException {

        System.out.println("Print hthssdss");
        SequenceDiagramParser sequenceDiagramParser=new SequenceDiagramParser();
        try 
        {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            File file = new File("C:/Users/ATIT/Documents/Altova/UModel2010/UModelExamples/NewOne.xmi");

            //sequenceDiagramParser = ;
            parser.parse(file, sequenceDiagramParser);
        } 
        catch (SAXException ex) 
        {
            System.out.println("Print hthss");
            Logger.getLogger(FindLocationMessage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        lifelineList = sequenceDiagramParser.getComponentList();

        for(Lifeline l: lifelineList)
            {
                System.out.println(l.getName().toString());
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What IDE are you using?
If you are using netbeans, then try the following:

- Disable "Deploy On Save" in Project Properties/Run
- Disable "Compile On Save" in Project Properties/Build/Compiling
- Try cleaning up the build
- On windows, search %APPDATA% in start search, then delete everything in .netbeans/6.9/var/cache/index/

These are just some solutions I found within a few minutes of searching. Good luck, and happy coding!